# Flask File Upload fails with 404 error

Tags: python, file, flask, upload, http-status-code-404

While following the Flask documentation / tutorials on how to upload a file I used this code:

main.py:

```
try:
  # import python modules
  import sys
  import config
  import os
  import inspect
  import datetime
  from flask import Flask,render_template,jsonify,redirect,url_for,request
  from werkzeug import secure_filename
except ImportError as e:
  print "Import error:", e, "\nAborting the program", __version__
  sys.exit()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfig')

def allowed_file(filename):
  return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     file = request.files['file']
     if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)  
        filename = os.path.join(app.config['CSV_FOLDER'], filename)
        return jsonify({"success": "True", "post": "none"})
     else:
        return jsonify({"success": "False", "post": "Invalid filename"})
  else:
     return jsonify({"success": "False", "post": "POST request required!"})
```

config.py:

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
    SECRET_KEY = ""
    CSV_FOLDER = "static/csv"
```

The above works well when running it on localhost on my Windows machine. When I upload this to my Hostmonster site, I get an 404 http-status-code (page not found).

This is my Hostmonster .htaccess file (stored in /GKS):

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /GKS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gks.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this is a picture of my folder structure on the Hostmonster site:
[Hostmonster folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj1yH.jpg)
If I look at the browser Dev Console I see this add'l error msg: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.".  Not sure if this has anything to do with my file upload.

Please help since I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem! I used the url '/upload' in my Javascript.  For whatever reason that worked in the Localhost development environment, but not on the live site. When I changed that to 'upload' all is well.

Hope this will help someone in the future.